# Consecutive visits

Tags: bug

My stat for consecutive visits is missing a day and was reset on Saturday, 12 October. I did visit that day on my mobile phone a number of times and yet it wasn't registered for some reason...

I had over 200 consecutive days prior to this issue.

Comment: I ran into this with mine just 8 days shy of hitting 100. I was so peeved...would have gotten that pretty little gold badge!!

Comment: Get a life, you two! *(/me checks consecutive stats...)*

Comment: You should ask for you money back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you hit the site from your smart phone several times on Sat, 12 October, but you didn't actually *use* the site. Looking at the home page does not count.

Unfortunately, after years of following up on reports of bugs for "missed days", I have never (not once) come across a case of miscalculating hits for the Enthusiast or Fanatic Badge.

More often than not, the problem is that Stack Exchange uses the UTC timezone… so if you visited the site on one day, and then much later on the *next* day, it is possible to miss the 24-hour windows in Stack Exchange time. We see a lot of "missed days" over the weekend because their routine of *when* they visit changes over the weekend. That's not what happened in this case, but it is quite common.

Another common problem is when users visit the site using their smartphone and don't realize they are *not* logged in. You were fine there, too, but that happens a lot.

I know this all seems a bit wonky, but no matter what timezone we choose, users are going to live in a different timezone. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to make it any easier for well-meaning folks to earn the badge without inviting large-scale cheating from others.

Sorry about the inconvenience. I hope it works out better the next time.

Comment: Thank you for *actually* looking into it -- you're absolutely right, hitting the home page was probably what I did those days. I didn't realize that didn't count - will be mindful for the future.

Comment: In addition, I already have the Fanatic badge - tmk it can't be awarded more than once - it was more a question of knowing exactly how addicted I am! thanks again.